# Align text in a floated left ul list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pUuFb/

How do I align the third element to be on the same line as the first two elements? I've tried `vertical-align: bottom` but it doesn't work. This seems like a really obvious thing that I'm missing. Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the CSS for the list item and div to:

```
li {
    margin: 0 20px 0 5px;
    display: inline;
}
div {
    display: inline;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pUuFb/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class `date`

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>
    <div>
        July 2nd
    </div>
</li>
```